# Who hires non-native English teachers?

Tags: work, languages

Most temporary jobs for foreign English teachers around the world, in places like Thailand and Korea, seem to require the person to be a native speaker. Also very frequent to demand a TEFL.

I was wondering where this isn't a requirement. Maybe there are places that value the person's background more than where she is native from? Or maybe niches, such as English for doctors or lawyers, where knowledge of the field would be the most relevant skill?

Comment: Questions about working abroad are off-topic for this site, see the [FAQ](http://travel.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: Do you have some stats to back up that "most jobs" have such requirements. Definitely the most reputable ones, the ones that pay the best teacher wages do, but there's tons of more affordable ones that don't pay as well or have as high requirements. I have no idea what the ratio of the one to the other is.

Comment: No stats, just an impression based on what I've seen, so I added a 'seem to'. Thanks.

Comment: @MightyMover: It varies a lot from country to country. Richer countries with longer traditions of importing English teachers have the highest expectations. Poorer countries with huge demand will have lower requirements. Plus you can always take on private students.

Comment: While some questions on ESOL/TEFL can be on topic, just asking 'who hires non-native English teachers' really isn't a travel question.  However, the [expats proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38732/expatriates) may be worth supporting, as it's a SE site that would be worthwhile for this sort of question.  However, it's probably off topic for travel.se.

Comment: Thanks, Mark. Yeah, by "who" I meant regions, cities and countries, not necessarily individual employers. Expats site looks good.

Comment: @MightyMover if you reword it a bit about where rather than 'who' (eg countries), it might be amenable to reopening, if you wished.  If you decide to, just below the question there's a reopen button, once you've edited it, you can flag it for consideration, if you believe it to be more on topic.  It may be interesting to future viewers.

Answer (score 2):

**[Teach and Learn with Georgia](http://www.tlg.gov.ge/)** had a good number of non-native English speakers working as English teachers when I was there recently.

By far most of the teachers are native speakers from USA but there were also teachers from all over the world - they all had very good English though. Officially you'd be a volunteer but it does pay a little bit. I heard some teachers saying one of the attractions was that it's the easiest English teaching program to join, but I don't know if that's totally true. I also heard that as it gets more established (it's only just over two years old) they are upping their standards. I believe you need a university degree in any subject to qualify for instance.